# HTML: Set a variable representing a folder name

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and trying to set a variable in the html document so that other placeholders in the document are filled by it.

e.g.

```
<var> X = "filepath" <var>
```

which would fill multiple placeholders such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' media='all' href=" *X*/static/css/webslides.css">
```

Is there a way to achieve this in html? I am flexible to use css if the solution is simple but bare in mind that I am new and don't have much javascript knowledge hence my preference.

Comment: HTML is a static document format.  JS is the only way to manipulate it dynamically in a web browser.

Comment: You cant set variables in a html document

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, both of your responses missed the  nature of my question i.e. 'is it possible?' and 'if so how does one go about it". I have 2 comments and 2 downvotes. Could you explain why you did this if this was indeed you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by making a default path to all link or path you can use :

```
<base href="X/" target="_blank">
```

remove the "/"  if you want to add it yourself.

ex :

```
<a href="test.html"></a> //in here you're don't have to write X anymore.
```

Comment: Thank you Andre. You reframed my question nicely and (I hope) you did not downvote my question realising the nature of it. All the best.

Comment: Your welcome, mate happy coding. Well you know senior equal superior is everywhere. I never once downvote (i know exactly how it felt)  XD .